# Why instantiation fails for local variable but not for static?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I am trying to find an easy way (with pre C++11, ie no `decltype`) to document what requirements a template has on a type to work properly. Maybe there are better ways to do this. However, this is my question:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct Foo {
    static const int test = sizeof(T::size);
};

template <typename T> struct DetectAndError {
    DetectAndError() { int test = sizeof(T::size); }
};

struct Bar {};

int main() {
    Foo<Bar> x;                            // NO ERROR ? :/
    // std::cout << x.test << std::endl;   // ERROR :)
    // DetectAndError<Bar> y;              // ERROR :)
}
```

Why is `Foo<Bar> x;` not an error? 
For the other lines I get what I want:

```
error: 'size' is not a member of 'Bar'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the standard mandates that `test` will be instantiated only when it is used. Member variables/member functions/static members of a template class aren't instantiated without them being used.

In your case the moment you try to do a `x.test` compiler tries to find `test` and subsequently cannot do it as `x::size` is missing.

The behaviour is pretty much accepted and common and ofcourse as per the standard.

Comment: Somehow for functions this rule is very intuitive to almost everyone :)

Comment: hm ok, if it is defined like this, then I just have to accept that it is like this ;). I expected something different

Answer (score 5):

The other answer is valid, but here's some standardese for it:

> N4140 § 14.7.1 [temp.inst]/ 1 and 2
>
> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>   the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the
>   definitions, default arguments, or *exception-specification* s of the
>   class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations,
>   static data members and member templates; and it causes the implicit
>   instantiation of the definitions of unscoped member enumerations and
>   member anonymous unions.
>
> the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the
>   specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member
>   definition to exist; in particular, the initialization (and any
>   associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless
>   the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the
>   definition of the static data member to exist.

Thus, `test` is only declared in the first line, but yields an error when instantiation is attempted. As for `DetectAndError`, you're implicitly calling its default constructor. `typedef DetectAndError<Foo> foo` or `DetectAndError<Foo>* ptr` should compile with no problems